# Is lock needed for INSERT INTO ... SELECT value + 1 when value is UNIQUE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Say I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Do I need some kind of lock if I insert data like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(number)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(number), 0) + 1 FROM test;
```

In other words, if I have this statement executed in parallel multiple times, should I be worried that the same `number` could be inserted twice? I obviously will create a `UNIQUE` key (which will in fact be a composite key, that's why the classic `AUTO INCREMENT` feature does not fit my needs), but in that case should I be worry that a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` error might be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default InnoDB uses auto-commit mode, so each query is a single transaction. So it will automatically perform the necessary locking to prevent duplication.